# Rails 2.2.2 application_helper.rb methods - Migrate to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am migrating a Rails 2.2.2 app over to Rails 3 and apparently I have to move the methods that are located in application_helper.rb someplace else.

When I load the Rails 3 version of the page, that uses the methods from Rails 2.2.2 application_helper.rb, I get

```
undefined method 'my_method_in_application_helper_rb'
```

**Can someone please explain where the methods from application_helper.rb should go such that they are seen in Rails 3?**

Thanks!

Comment: where are u shifting the application_helper methods? why? i recently moved a application form rails 2 to rails 3 without shifting the helper methods and it works perfectly.

Comment: I used a migration script that put the methods in a different file with the file extension .rails2. I just copied the methods from there into the Rails 3 application_helper.rb file - All works now

Comment: why the .rails2 file? i dont get the intention. anyway, rails 3 wont load it since its not a .rb file.

Comment: The migration script that I used simply took whatever was in the Rails 2.2.2 application_helper.rb file and put it in a file called application_helper.rb.rails2 supposedly for safe keeping. I just had to take those methods in the .rails2 file and put them in the Rails 3 application_helper.rb file, which was empty.

Comment: ok, it was a backup copy. but if u shift the helper files from rails 2 app to rails 3 app, they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Rails migration script that put the Rails 2.2.2 application_helper.rb methods in a same-named file with the file extension .rails2. I just copied the methods from there into the Rails 3 application_helper.rb file - All works now